# Why can't I upgrade php?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, php

I am running Ubuntu desktop, here's my output from `lsb_release -a`

> ```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
> Release:  16.04
> Codename: xenial
> ```

When I run `apt update` I get:

> All packages are up to date.

Then running `php -v`

> ```
> PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>     with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
>     with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
> ```

However, I have another Ubuntu server running the same `lsb_release -a`

> ```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
> Release:  16.04
> Codename: xenial
> ```

But it has a newer version of PHP installed:

> ```
> PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>     with Zend OPcache v7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
> ```

I have no PPAs installed on either machine. How can I upgrade my desktop from 7.0.8 to 7.0.13 like what's running on my server?

Comment: I would investigate why php -v shows 16.04.3 at the end. That would indicate your 1st system is newer.

Comment: I agree that's strange because that's not even a [valid version number](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around for a while under `System Settings` > `Software & Updates` I remembered once upon a time that I disabled the install updates from the following sources because I got a little annoyed with the frequent interrupting pop-ups to upgrade. I prefer to manage my upgrades manually from `apt` on the terminal and I didn't want it to automatically upgrade me from 16.04 to 16.10 or some other release. What I didn't realize is that these checkboxes stripped the deb package sources from `/etc/apt/sources.list` so it would never fetch the package updates and always report my system was up-to-date. After checking those boxes and then running `apt update` and `upgrade` I was able to successfully install the new version `PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )`

[image: screenshot software and updates install updates from all]